# SockJs - 'info' path not found

Tags: node.js, sockjs

I'm running an [example of SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/tree/master/examples/echo).

Ran npm install (everything okay)

Start [server](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/echo/server.js) with no problem.

When I first load [the test page](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/echo/index.html), I see that there was a failed 404 call to`http://127.0.0.1/echo/info`

I'm looking at sockjs code and I'm guessing it is called from here - https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/src/sockjs.coffee#L81

What is the purpose of this info call and why is it not found? What am I missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is listening on 9999 port! So you have to put the port too.

This will work `http://127.0.0.1:9999/echo/info`

Comment: I'm providing port number (8080) and still facing the same problem, any solution.?

Comment: @masT As said above, server listens on 9999. So change 8080 to 9999. If it does not work, then something else is the issue. Ask a new question giving the details of the problem you faced.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605465/sockjs-info-causing-http-404-while-connecting-server