# SockJS - '/info' causing Http 404 while connecting server

Tags: java, push-notification, sockjs

I've mainly followed below posts for implementing push notifications using SockJS,

[Push Notifications for Java Webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474273/push-notification-for-java-web-app), [SockJS Client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client), [SockJS Java Server](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/java/sockjs/SockJSExample.java).

My sockJS client is:

```
var sock = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/pusher");

sock.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("message: " + event.data);
    alert('received message echoed from server: ' + event.data);
};
```

*Server is listening same port 8080. But while running I got error 404:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/pusher/info 404 (Not Found)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788628/sockjs-info-path-not-found) on StackOverflow doesn't solve my problem. Please check what I'm missing.
Do I need to register client or publish server to enable the push notifications. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try replacing localhost as your actual server IP address. It should work.

Comment: using http://127.0.0.1:8080/pusher results in same error sir.

Comment: Are you testing on your local machine ?

Comment: Yes sir, on tomcat. Server is listening port 8080.

Comment: Tomcat is for http server right. Do you have a sockJS server installed (the npm package) and running?

Comment: In this case, try to remove the specific http://localhost:8080, just create socket as new SockJS("/pusher") (NOTE: if you specific the context path, also add it before slash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must follow this pattern: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/examples/express-3.x/server.js

Pay close attention to the fact that calling `app.listen` will *NOT* work, you must call `server.listen`. So the `.listen` call must be on the http instance, not on the express instance.

Comment: The link is dead - https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/main/examples/express-3.x/server.js